# ASP Unterminated string constant error

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am receiving the following error and I don't understand how to fix it.

The error:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0409'

Unterminated string constant

/junk/airsearch/search.htm, line 118

response.write("
----------------^
```

ASP code responsible:

```
  <% if con("notes") = "" then
  response.write("")
  else
  response.write("
  <tr>
    <td colspan='8'><strong>Notes:</strong> con('notes')</td>
  </tr>")
  endif
  %>
```

Entire page code:

```
<%@CODEPAGE=65001%> 
<%
pagetitle="Aircraft and Simulator Multi-use List 06/074"
%>
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/header.htm"-->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/menu.htm"-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})
$('#supplier_name, #aircraft_type').focus()
$("#supplier_name").val($("#supplier_name").val());
$("#aircraft_type").val($("#aircraft_type").val());
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 800;  

$('#supplier_name, #aircraft_type').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#supplier_name, #aircraft_type').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

function doneTyping () {
    $("form").submit();
}

});
</script>
<div class="twoColumnRow">
<div class="twoColumnContent">
<p class="breadCrm"><a href="/index.htm">Home</a> <span>&gt;</span> <a href="/tools/index.htm">Tools of the Trade</a> <span>&gt;</span> <a href="/tools/finance/index.htm">Finance and Purchasing</a><span>&gt;</span> <a href="/tools/finance/procurement/index.htm">Procurement and Contracts information</a></p>
<div class="contentPad">
<!-- Start of main content -->

<p class="imageRight">&nbsp;</p>
<h1><%=pagetitle%></h1>

<%
        Dim connectString, connect, conDB, sconDB, lDB, con, scon, lcon, src_ccn, src_state
        connectString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("data")
              src_supplier_name = Request.QueryString("supplier_name")
              src_aircraft_type = Request.QueryString("aircraft_type")
              src_state = Request.QueryString("state")
        set connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        connect.open connectString

        if src_state = "" then
            conDB = "SELECT * FROM mul.csv WHERE ucase(supplier_name) LIKE ucase('%"+src_supplier_name+"%') AND ucase(aircraft_type) LIKE ucase('%"+src_aircraft_type+"%')"   
            lDB = "SELECT * FROM mul.csv WHERE ucase(supplier_name) LIKE ucase('%"+src_supplier_name+"%')" 
        elseif src_state = "any" then
            conDB = "SELECT * FROM mul.csv WHERE ucase(supplier_name) LIKE ucase('%"+src_supplier_name+"%') AND ucase(aircraft_type) LIKE ucase('%"+src_aircraft_type+"%')"   
            lDB = "SELECT * FROM mul.csv WHERE ucase(supplier_name) LIKE ucase('%"+src_supplier_name+"%') AND ucase(aircraft_type) LIKE ucase('%"+src_aircraft_type+"%')" 
        else 
            conDB = " SELECT * FROM mul.csv WHERE ucase(state) LIKE ucase('%"+src_state+"%') AND ucase(supplier_name) LIKE ucase('%"+src_supplier_name+"%') AND ucase(aircraft_type) LIKE ucase('%"+src_aircraft_type+"%')"
            lDB = " SELECT * FROM mul.csv WHERE ucase(state) LIKE ucase('%"+src_state+"%') AND ucase(supplier_name) LIKE ucase('%"+src_supplier_name+"%') AND ucase(aircraft_type) LIKE ucase('%"+src_aircraft_type+"%')"
        end if

        sconDB = "SELECT * FROM mul.csv"    

        set con = connect.execute(conDB)
        set scon = connect.execute(sconDB)
        set lcon = connect.execute(lDB)
%>
<h2>Search results</h2>
<% if not con.BOF then %>
<div style="margin-top:1em">

  <form id="searchf" action="search.htm" method="get">

      <p>Supplier name: <input id="supplier_name" name="supplier_name" type="text" value="<%=src_supplier_name%>"> Aircraft type: <input id="aircraft_type" name="aircraft_type" type="text" value="<%=src_aircraft_type%>"> </p>
     <p>State or Territory:<br/>
      <select style="width: 497px;" id="state" name="state">
        <option class="group" label="Any state or territory" value="any" <%if request.querystring("state") = "any" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Australian Capital Territory" value="ACT" <%if request.querystring("state") = "ACT" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="New South Whales" value="NSW" <%if request.querystring("state") = "NSW" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Northern Territory" value="NT" <%if request.querystring("state") = "NT" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Queensland" value="QLD" <%if request.querystring("state") = "QLD" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="South Australia" value="SA" <%if request.querystring("state") = "SA" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Tasmania" value="TAS" <%if request.querystring("state") = "TAS" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Victoria" value="VIC" <%if request.querystring("state") = "VIC" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Western Australia" value="WA" <%if request.querystring("state") = "WA" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Other" value="other" <%if request.querystring("state") = "other" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
      </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
  </form>
  <br />

<table style="font-size:.9em;" class="contentTable">
  <tr>
    <th width="25%">Supplier</th>
    <th width="5%">State</th>
    <th width="20%">Aircraft type</th>
    <th width="10%">Variant</th>
    <th width="10%">Hourly cost</th>
    <th width="10%">Rental basis</th>
    <th width="10%">Timing method</th>
    <th width="10%">Insurance excess</th>

  </tr>
  <% con.Movefirst() %>
  <% while (NOT con.EOF) %>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="searchcomp.htm?ccn=<%=con("ccn")%>"><%=con("supplier_name")%></a></td>
    <td><%=con("state")%></td>
    <td><%=con("aircraft_type")%></td>
    <td><%=con("variant")%></td>
    <td><%=con("cost_hr")%></td>
    <td><%=con("rental_basis")%></td>
    <td><%=con("timing_method")%></td>
    <td><%=con("insurance_excess")%></td>
  </tr>
  <% if con("notes") = "" then
  response.write("")
  else
  response.write("
  <tr>
    <td colspan='8'><strong>Notes:</strong> con('notes')</td>
  </tr>")
  endif
  %>
  <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
  %>
</table>

</div>
<% else %>
    <% scon.Movefirst() %>
  <form id="searchf" action="search.htm" method="get">

      <p>Supplier name: <input id="supplier_name" name="supplier_name" type="text" value="<%=src_supplier_name%>"> Aircraft type: <input id="aircraft_type" name="aircraft_type" type="text" value="<%=src_aircraft_type%>"> </p>
     <p>State or Territory:<br/>
      <select style="width: 497px;" id="state" name="state">
        <option class="group" label="Any state or territory" value="any" <%if request.querystring("state") = "any" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Australian Capital Territory" value="ACT" <%if request.querystring("state") = "ACT" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="New South Whales" value="NSW" <%if request.querystring("state") = "NSW" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Northern Territory" value="NT" <%if request.querystring("state") = "NT" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Queensland" value="QLD" <%if request.querystring("state") = "QLD" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="South Australia" value="SA" <%if request.querystring("state") = "SA" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Tasmania" value="TAS" <%if request.querystring("state") = "TAS" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Victoria" value="VIC" <%if request.querystring("state") = "VIC" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Western Australia" value="WA" <%if request.querystring("state") = "WA" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
        <option class="group" label="Other" value="other" <%if request.querystring("state") = "other" then response.write("selected") %>></option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <br /><hr />
<p>No records match your query.</p>
<p><a href="dbtest.htm">Return to search page</a></p>
<%
  end if
  con.close
%>


<!-- End of main content -->
</div> <!-- end contentPad div -->
</div> <!-- end twocolumncontent div -->
<div class="twoColumnLinks">

<!--<div class="relatedLinks">
<h3>Related Links</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="/index.htm">Related link 1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>--> <!-- end relatedlinks div -->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/quicklinks.htm"-->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/mylinks.htm"-->
</div> <!-- end twocolumnlinks div -->
</div> <!-- end twocolumnrow div -->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/_lib/include/footer.htm"-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have strings on multiple lines.

Either put the string all on one line, or end the string at the end of the line and concateneate it with the string on the next line and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three different ways of formatting your code to achieve what you'd like:

```
<% Dim con_notes : con_notes = con("notes") %>

<% if con_notes = "" then
response.write("")
else
response.write("<tr>")
response.write("  <td colspan='8'><strong>Notes:</strong> " & con_notes & "</td>")
response.write("</tr>")
end if
%>
```

or

```
<% if con_notes <> "" then %>
<tr>
  <td colspan="8"><strong>Notes:</strong> <%=con_notes %></td>
</tr>
<% end if %>
```

or

```
<%
if con_notes <> "" then
  response.write "<tr>" & _
                   "<td colspan='8'><strong>Notes:</strong> " & _
                   con_notes & _
                   "</td>" & _
                 "</tr>"
end if
%>
```

I tend to prefer the second way of formatting my code.

Comment: Spaghetti in its best... reminds me why I prefer ASP.NET so much.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You don't like spaghetti..?! ;-)